# Como integrar o File Manager (CKEditor) com o AWS S3?

Tags: ckeditor, laravel-5.3, amazon-aws

Estou utilizando o `CKEditor` com o `Laravel 5.3` e preciso salvar as imagens e arquivos no `S3 (AWS)`. Na parte do `Laravel` está funcionando, mas, no `File Manager` do `CKEditor` não.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Amigo, coloque a dificuldade que você esta enfrentando para realizar a implementação para que alguém possa te instruir na solução.

Comment: O File Manager quando instalado no Laravel nos dá um arquivo de configuração (lfm.php), ao configurá-lo dá o seguinte erro:
**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'A facade root has not been set.**
O código:

`images_dir'            => Storage::disk('s3')->url('ckfinder/userfiles/images'),
    'images_url'            => Storage::disk('s3')->url('ckfinder/userfiles/images'),

    'files_dir'             => Storage::disk('s3')->url('ckfinder/userfiles/files'),
    'files_url'             => Storage::disk('s3')->url('ckfinder/userfiles/files'),`

Comment: Já avancei mais que isso, mas tive que mexer nos controllers do File Manager, dentro do diretório vendor do Laravel, mas creio que isso não seja bom. No caso de uma atualização, por exemplo, vai dar dor de cabeça.

Comment: Só para constar, a façade está configurada corretamente, tanto que funciona pro resto do sistema:
`'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,`